# Cauchy Sequence that is not Monotone

Tags: real-analysis

I claim that $a_n$=$\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ satisfies this as it converges to 0 from quadrant 1 and quadrant 4 simultaneously. I am sure there is a proper mathematical way to say that. I am stuck on how to prove that this is a Cauchy sequence. Do I use induction? if so, why?

My attempt at a proof:

let $\epsilon > 0$

there exists M$\in\mathbb{N}$ st M > $\frac{10}{\epsilon}$

so $n_1k$$\geq$M implies $\frac{1}{n}$$\leq$$\frac{1}{M}$$<$$\frac{\epsilon}{10}$

*For this proof so  far I picked M based on looking at the graph, is this appropriate? Also, not sure how to treat my $a_n$ in terms of the (-1)^n, do i need to consider both cases when n is even or odd?

Comment: Why are you talking about quadrants?  This is a sequence of real numbers and, as such, are on the real line, not in two dimensional space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then if $n > 2\epsilon$, you have 
$$\left|{(-1)^n\over n}\right| < {\epsilon\over 2}.$$  Moreover, if 
$m, n > 2/\epsilon$, you have
$$\left|{(-1)^n\over n} - {(-1)^m\over m}\right| < \epsilon.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be known, choose $N = 1+\lfloor\dfrac{2}{\epsilon}\rfloor$, then:

$ \left|a_m - a_n\right| \leq |a_m| + |a_n| \leq \dfrac{1}{m} + \dfrac{1}{n} \leq \dfrac{2}{n} < \epsilon$

for $m, n > N$.